# How to add a submit button in an HTML table?

Tags: hooks

I need to call the gh_cart_prove when the BUTTON is clicked.

```
function gh_view_categories(){
  $a='<table>';
  $a.='<tr>';
  $a.='<td><strong>'.'Categoria:'.'</strong></td>';
  $a.='<td><strong>'.'Soglia minima:'.'</strong></td>';
  $a.='<td><strong>'.'Tot attuale:'.'</strong></td>';
  $a.='<td><strong>'.'Crea ordine'.'</strong></td>';
  $a.='</tr>';
  $query = db_select('uc_product_classes', 'u')
    ->fields('u', array('name','soglia', 'totattuale'));
  $result = $query->execute();
  while ($record = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
    $idUser=gh_get_user_id($record['name']);
    $a.='<tr>';
    $a.='<td>'.$record['name'].'</td>';
    $a.='<td>'.$record['soglia'].'</td>';
    $a.='<td>'.$record['totattuale'].'</td>';
    $a.='<td>'.'<button onClick="gh_cart_prove($idUser)">BUTTON</button>'.'</td>';
    $a.='</tr>';

  }

  $a.='</table>';

  return ($a);
}
```

The button appear but it not works. the function is correctly declared.
How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Is `gh_cart_prove()` a JavaScript function?

Comment: no it isn't....

Comment: if gh_cart_prove is NOT a JS, it may help to get an answer if you EDIT your question to explain what it IS ...

Comment: I would assume that you have `gh_cart_prove()` as a PHP function in a contributed module? What I don't see here is a <form> element. If you want to handle it like a form, I would recommend placing one in your table (even if it's within your existing <td>). Otherwise, Javascript would be your best approach.

Answer (score 1):

Assign an id to the button and use Jquery, 
set the $idUser in a data attribute example :

```
 <button id="buddon-id" data-user="<?php echo $idUser;?>" >button</button>
    <script>
    $("#button-id").on("click", function(e){
       userid = $(this).attr("data-user");
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi Riccardo, thanks a lot.. I'm new with jquery, Where do I put the code of the script? in what way?

Comment: I suggest you to create a js file and insert the path in the yourthemename.info file, install jquery update module and add the code after $ = JQuery; 
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $ = jQuery;
//.... your code here
});